# It is possible to navigate through an external website or web application using an HTML iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am currently working on a PaaS (platform as a service) where frontend can be developed using html5 (yes, I am limited to using vanilla js)

I must show within an html document an external web application that belongs to me, either using iframe or some other alternative and guarantee that this external app is fully functional while being embedded within the page.

The problem I am currently having is that with "iframe" or with alternatives such as "embed" or "object" you cannot navigate beyond the page that is brought up through the url, for example you cannot exit the page login embedded in an iframe, when I try to login the page in the iframe it just restarts.

here some examples:

```
<iframe src="url_to_myapp" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen>
```

```
<embed src="url_to_myapp" quality="medium" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550" height="400" name="whoosh" align="middle"
allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="true">
```

Is it possible to navigate between different pages of the same website or through the internet using an iframe? If not, is there an alternative in html5 where it is possible to show an embedded page inside another and navigate through it?

thank you, greetings

Comment: Couldn't you change the `src` of your `iframe` to move to different pages of the site? [how-to-navigate-url-in-an-iframe-with-javascript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-navigate-url-in-an-iframe-with-javascript/)

Comment: Is page you are displaying frame on same origin as frame origin? You used to be able to easily navigate to other pages inside a frame but security keeps tightening on them. [Here's a primitive demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QB9s0ckzxyHQ4WGA) of clicking links in an iframe that load a new page in same frame. You might also want to read up on [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options). It's possible you have some conflicting headers also

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36526704/2813224) works depending on the site's security.